# How to Convert DateTime to string in linq query c#

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I am getting data using linq query in binding to model class properties like

```
var employeesNotEnteredTimesheetList = 
    ( from emps in reslandentity.EMPLOYEE
      join notify in reslandentity.NOTIFICATION 
        on emps.NOTIFICATION_ID equals notify.ID
      from week in reslandentity.WEEK_CALENDER
      from statlk in reslandentity.STATUS_LKUP
      where !reslandentity.TIMESHEET.Any( m => m.RES_ID == empid && 
                                               m.WEEK_CAL_ID == week.ID && 
                                               m.COMP_ID == Companyid && 
                                               m.RES_TYPE == "EMPLOYEE"
                                        ) &&
            week.WEEK_START_DT.Month == month &&
            week.WEEK_START_DT.Year == year &&
            emps.COMP_ID == Companyid &&
            emps.ID == empid &&
            statlk.TYPE == "TIMESHEET" &&
            statlk.STATE == "NOT_ENTERED" &&
            week.WEEK_START_DT <= thisWeekStartDate &&
            emps.IS_DELETED == "N"

     select new TimesheetModel
     {
         EMP_ID = emps.ID,
         EMP_COMP_ID = emps.COMP_EMP_ID,
         EMPLOYEE_NAME = emps.FIRST_NAME + " " + emps.LAST_NAME,
         PrimaryEmail = notify.PRI_EMAIL_ID,
         DESCR = statlk.DESCR,
         RES_TYPE = "EMPLOYEE",
         START_DATE =week.WEEK_START_DT.ToString(), // Getting Error here when executing query
         EDate = week.WEEK_END_DT,
         EMP_STATUS = "NOT_ENTERED"
     } ).Distinct().ToList();
```

I want to convert datetime to string in the model class, but not getting, i have tried like toString(), ConvertToString().. but not getting. How to convert to string, please help me anyone.. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i think in your `TimesheetModel` model you have define `START_DATE` as datetime please change it to `string` and try again.

Comment: @sanjay I'm not 100% sure but I think you can't use `ToString()` in LINQ2SQL queries. I guess that you get error about this. P.S Maybe it's not in `LINQ2SQL` in general but only when you are using `EF`. Include the error and if you are using `EF`.

Comment: What ARE you getting? And what is the error message?

Comment: Is this Entity Framework? EF does not support `ToString`.

Comment: @CoryNelson Yes it does support ToString () now. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/03/17/ef6-1-0-rtm-available.aspx

Comment: Which version of EF are you using ?

Comment: I got the solution by writing like DateTime SDate.ToShortDateString()

Answer (score 1):

ToString is not available in this context.

Update your time sheet model so that start date is of type DateTime. That will allow your assignment.

Then either create a second 'get' only property which returns the .ToString() of start date...

```
Public string StartDateString
{
    get{ return this.StartDate.ToString();}
}
```

...or simply keep it as DateTime and convert it when used. This will give you better support for through strong types.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of START_DATE to string and stay with your code.

OR

Make a DateTime? datatype to START_DATE something like:

`DateTime? START_DATE;` ...

and remove the `.toString()` in your linq;

since your fetching START_DATE, convert it to string if you will now use it.

```
START_DATE.toString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Something like that